# Windows 8.1 Basic theme?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, themes, dwm

Is there a good way to enable the real 8.1 Basic theme? Not the "Aero Lite" theme, it's pretty ugly, and not a 3rd party theme since they still resemble normal Aero. The only partially working method is by killing Explorer, suspending winlogon, and killing DWM. Restarting Explorer leaves a huge chunk of the right side of the screen frozen. Are there better ways, or a fix for the glitch? I suspect it may be charms bar but I'm not completely sure.

Edit: I've found what I'm looking for; [BasicThemer2](https://github.com/Ingan121/BasicThemer2/releases/latest), which applies the Windows Basic theme to Windows Vista through 10, without disabling desktop composition.

Comment: You can just just a plain, single color (blue) background for a theme. That is, no theme. That worked for me when I had Windows 8 and I still adhere to that practice.

Comment: @John Windows Basic theme includes a different window UI that is very different from the default one. Simply changing a color wouldn't do much, considering the basic theme is also designed to be lightweight compared to the default theme.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I removed themes and just used a colored background. That is what I meant by no theme.

Comment: Is there an image or mockup? Windows 8 has a theme setting. Have you tried that? Using just words it is very difficult to tell what, precisely, you are asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has indicated they found a solution to their problem in the current revision of the question.